# Re-defining Shader variables draws them all?

Tags: glsl, shader, glsles

I'm fairly new to shaders and came across the Book of Shaders [website](https://thebookofshaders.com/05/). Early on, this piece of code appears and surprisingly he didn't teach about how variables work yet so I can't get my head around  the `color` variable. This code simultaneously displays a left to right fading background (black to white) and a green diagonal line.

So, essentially, you declare `vec3` color to be `vec3(y)` which means all the 3 `r,g,b` values will be same throughout. I get why the fading background occurs because r, g, b stay equal and range between 0 and 1.

But coming from a JS and PHP background, normally if I change the value of a variable later, only the new value is accepted. So I was expecting that the lerping value out of `color = (1.0-pct)*color+pct*vec3(0.0,1.0,0.0);` would overwrite the previous `vec3 color = vec3(y);` and be considered for `gl_FragColor` function. But it appears both the versions of `color` are drawn: the fading BG and the green line. Is this how the shader code works, by drawing every definition of a variable?

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform vec2 u_mouse;
uniform float u_time;

// Plot a line on Y using a value between 0.0-1.0
float plot(vec2 st) {    
    return smoothstep(0.02, 0.0, abs(st.y - st.x));
}

void main() {
    vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy/u_resolution;

    float y = st.x;

    vec3 color = vec3(y);

    // Plot a line
    float pct = plot(st);
    color = (1.0-pct)*color+pct*vec3(0.0,1.0,0.0);

    gl_FragColor = vec4(color,1.0);
}
```

Comment: @Rabbid76 thank you but I still can't understand what is making the line and background draw simultaneously? For me `color` is just one vec3 function.

Comment: So let me ask this instead, there are 2 interpolations going on. One in `smoothStep` and the other in the lerp function inside `color`. Are these 2 responsible for the line and fading bg respectively?

Comment: The fragment shader is executed for each fragment (pixel). The output of the fragment shader (`gl_FragColor`) depends on the coordinate of the fragment (`gl_FragCoord.xy`). This creates the color gradient.

Answer (score 2):

First `vec3 color = vec3(y);` declares `color` and assigns the right to left black and white gradient to it. Then, `color = (1.0-pct)*color+pct*vec3(0.0,1.0,0.0);` assigns an new value to color which is a lerp between its old value (`color`), and its new value `vec3(0.0,1.0,0.0)` (green). It is equivalent to do :

```
color *= (1.0-pct);
color += pct*vec3(0.0,1.0,0.0);
```

The old value **is** overwritten but as **the new definition uses this old value**, you can still see the background gradient.

Comment: Thank you very much. So if I understand it correctly, it is like brush strokes in real painting. Every definition of `color` will be counted as a new brush stroke on the canvas and added on top of the previous drawing/strokes. Right?

Comment: Only if you reuse color in it's new definition, if you don't it will be completely replaced. It is like in any other language.

Comment: to make a parallel, it is like creating a number in two times by first creating its fracional part with `float n = 0.125;` and then adding the integer part with `n = n + 452.0;` (and not just `n = 452.0;` because it would just replace the first value).